# How to instruct highcharts scatter chart to print all dataLabels

Tags: javascript, charts, highcharts, overlap

I have a scatter-chart which uses dataLabels on certain elements to quickly show information about the item.

This is chart-definition:

```
    chart: {
        type: 'scatter',
        height: 700
    },

    series: [
        {
                data: [
    { marker: { enabled: true }, x: 1, y: 18
    , dataLabels: { enabled: true, formatter: function () { return '1.0.0.1197';             } } 
    }, 
    { marker: { enabled: true }, x: 1, y: 16
    , dataLabels: { enabled: true, formatter: function () { return '1.0.0.1212';             } } 
    }, 
    { marker: { enabled: true }, x: 1, y: 15
    , dataLabels: { enabled: true, formatter: function () { return '1.0.0.1213';             } } 
    }, 
    { marker: { enabled: true }, x: 1, y: 0
    , dataLabels: { enabled: true, formatter: function () { return '1.0.0.1197';             } } 
    }
        ]
    }
    ]
};
```

See https://jsfiddle.net/centic/gy4p6ej1/5/ for the live results, it does not show the dataLabel for 1.0.0.1213.

If I set the chart-height higher, it starts displaying the label, but I would like to force highcharts to show all the labels that I define, even if they overlap and with the current height, as there might be more data-points being added in the future.

I already tried with some of the settings like allowOverlap, crop, ... but none of them made a difference!

Comment: here's the updated code: https://jsfiddle.net/gy4p6ej1/7/

Comment: You can try to set [padding](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.series.dataLabels.padding) as 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set `allowOverlap: true`, like this:

```
plotOptions: {
    series: {
        dataLabels: {
            allowOverlap: true
        }
    }
}
```

See [this updated JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gy4p6ej1/9/) demonstration.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I only tried on the specific dataLabel inside the data-elements, not on the series itself, that did the trick!